# How to disallow WCF metadata / wsdl

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Is there a way to block the WSDL information on a WCF service. Looking for ways to improve security, blocking access to the WSDL seems like a great way to start.

Any other recommendations also welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Configuration to disable WCF metadata:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="Service1Behavior">
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```